# An assignment problem( in elementary number theory course) on which i am struck and need help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying assignment and I am unable to think about this problem. Can someone please help.

> Question is ->   prove that $ (n-1)^2  $  divides $ n^k -1$ iff (n-1) divides k.

I shall be really grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

Let $n-1=m,n=?$

Using binomial expansion,

$$n^k-1=(1+m)^k-1\equiv \binom k1m^1\pmod{m^2}$$

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @XWLPDK, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$n^k-1=(n-1)(n^{k-1}+n^{k-2}+..+n+1) =(n-1) \left( n^{k-1}-1+n^{k-1}-1+...+n-1+k\right)\\
=(n-1) \left( n^{k-1}-1+n^{k-1}-1+...+n-1\right)+k(n-1) $$

Now use the fact that in the first bracket you can factor out an $(n-1)$ from each term.

Comment: Can the downvotter explain?