# Prove this statement for m>1 and n>2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I’m super new to number theory and here is a question from a textbook:

Prove this : if $1\le m$ and $2\le n$ ,m and n are natural numbers then we have :
$$(n-1)^2|(n^m-1) \iff (n-1)|m$$

I even appreciate a hint or guiding me through the answer.

Comment: Hey! What have you tried so far? Are you sure that the greater or equal sign is in the correct direction?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535664/an-assignment-problem-in-elementary-number-theory-course-on-which-i-am-struck

Answer (score 2):

Factorize the value of $n^m-1$ as below:
$$(n-1)(n^{m-1}+n^{m-2}+\cdots+n+1)$$
Now, the second factor has to be divisible by $(n-1)$. It has $m$ terms. All of them are $1 \bmod{(n-1)}$. Can you complete the proof? Can you use this same factorization to show the converse?