# $(n-1)^2$ divides $(n^k -1) $ if and only if $(n-1)$ divides $k$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> $(n-1)^2$ divides $(n^k -1) $ if and only if  $(n-1)$ divides $k$
> where $n\geq 2$ and $ n \geq 1$

$$n^k-1 =  (n-1)(n^{k-1} + n^{k-2} + \ldots + 2 + 1)$$

So $$(n-1)^2 \;\big|\;(n^k-1) \iff (n-1) \; \big| \;  (n^{k-1} + n^{k-2} + \ldots + 2 + 1)$$

So I want to prove $(n-1) \; \big| \;  (n^{k-1} + n^{k-2} + \ldots + 2 + 1) $ if and only if $ (n-1) \; \big| \; k$

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you mean $n\ge 2$ and $k\ge 1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535664/an-assignment-problem-in-elementary-number-theory-course-on-which-i-am-struck/3535667#3535667